# Discord.py react on certain emoji doesnt work

Tags: python, pycharm, discord.py

Im creating a game with discord.py and for now i have tried to fix one problem for a few hours but with no success.

Here is the code, someone will type !game and then the bot sends a random map from that i have made, add four arrows to the message and waits for someone to react. My problem is that when someone reacts i get an error:

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'reaction'

I dont know what to use instead of message, i have tried many things but none of them worked.

Also here is how it looks in discord:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zg2LR.png)

```
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 60.0, commands.BucketType.guild)
async def game(msg):
    message = await msg.send(random.choice(mapy))
    await message.add_reaction("⬆️")
    await message.add_reaction("⬇️")
    await message.add_reaction("⬅️")
    await message.add_reaction("➡️")
    await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check=lambda reaction, user: reaction.emoji == "⬆️" or "⬇️" or "⬅️" or "➡️")
    if message.reaction.emoji == "⬆️":
        await msg.send("up")
    if message.reaction.emoji == "⬇️":
        await msg.send("down")
    if message.reaction.emoji == "⬅️":
        await msg.send("left")
    if message.reaction.emoji == "➡️":
        await msg.send("right")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `discord.Message` doesn't have the attribute `reaction` it's `reactions`
2. You're waiting for a reaction, you can simply assign it to a variable

```py
reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", ...)

if str(reaction) == "⬆️":
    ...

# And so on
```

EDIT

```py
check = lambda reaction, user: return str(reaction) in ["⬆️", "⬇️", "⬅️", "➡️"]
```

Comment: It doesnt work for some reason, now when i add a reaction nothing happens.

Comment: Yes, there's a logic problem in the lambda function, let me edit my answer

Comment: It works, but only when i removed return from the user:

reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", check = lambda reaction, user: str(reaction) in ["⬆️", "⬇️", "⬅️", "➡️"])
if str(reaction) == "⬆️":
   await msg.send("up")

Also i realised that it only works when there is only one if statement, if i add another for, lets say, arrow left, both arrow up and left dont work.